# .htaccess simple rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, pattern-matching, url-rewriting

For some reason this isn't working, am I missing something obvious?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)infopopup.html$ /acatalog/infopopup.html
```

Comment: Did you try checking if `rewrite` module is enabled? Also, you may want to escape that dot in `.html`

Comment: Yes rewrite is enabled as I have a few other rewrites. When this line is entered I get an Internet Server Error with and without out escaping the dot...

Comment: You need to put more information - there are logs you know ;)

Comment: Which log would it be logged in?

Comment: I think that the error is a looping error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to exclude your target file from the RewriteRule because this may cause an infinite loop of rewrites:

```
RewriteRule ^acatalog/infopopup.html - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)infopopup.html$ acatalog/infopopup.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a looping issue, here's what ended up working:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/acatalog/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)infopopup.html$ acatalog/infopopup.html [QSA,L]
```